# How can I show data in second GridView depends on first GridView when clicked on select?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have two instances of `GridView` and two of `DataSources`. I have a relation of 1:(many). I need to show data in the second `GridView` depending on the first `GridView` when I click on "*SELECT*". I need to solve that using ASP.NET but directly on the mark-up document (i.e. ASPX), as opposed to in the code behind (i.e. CS).

The first `GridView` object:

```
<asp:GridView 
     ID = "GridView1" 
     runat = "server" 
     DataKeyNames = "ID_Segment" 
     DataSourceID = "DSSegment">
     <Columns>
       ...
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The first `DataSource` object:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
     ID = "DSSegment"
     runat = "server" 
     ConnectionString = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:PraxeConnectionString %>"
     ... 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The second `GridView` object:

```
<asp:GridView 
     ID = "GridView2" 
     runat = "server" 
     DataKeyNames = "ID_Podsit" 
     DataSourceID = "DSPodsit">
     <Columns>
       ...
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The second `DataSource` object:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
     ID = "DSPodsit"
     runat = "server" 
     ConnectionString = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:PraxeConnectionString %>" 
     ...
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First GridView - redirecting back to the page with a new QueryString

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="GridView1" 
        runat="server" 
        DataKeyNames="ID_Segment" 
        DataSourceID="DSSegment">
        <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
               <a href='/?SegmentID=<%#Eval("ID_Segment")%>'>Select this</a>
           </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

2nd Datasource - Uses the querystring

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSPodsit" runat="server" 

     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PraxeConnectionString %>" 
        ... SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tTable WHERE SegmentID=@SegmentID">

   <asp:QueryStringParameter name="SegmentID" QueryStringField="SegmentID" />

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can also find more clues here [Master GridView with a Details DetailView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx)